# Underscore-italics nested inside double-star-bolding doesn't work in comments.

Tags: bug, comments, markdown

One expects the following two pieces of markdown to produce identical results:

```
**bold *bold italics***
**bold _bold italics_**
```

In the body of a post, they do:

> **bold *bold italics***
>
> **bold *bold italics***

But in a comment, they don't:

[image]

I'm guessing this is something to do with the markdown parser interpreting `italics_**` as a single word with an internal underscore, but... that's dumb and it shouldn't do that. In any case, the behavior of `**foo _bar_**` ought to be consistent between posts and comments.

Comment: `**bold *bold italics*** **bold _bold italics_**` renders as: **bold *bold italics*** **bold _bold italics_**